# Angularjs get element position

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In jQuery we can get position of an object with this:

```
$(this).position().left;
```

How can we get the current element position with AngularJS?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use prop() from angular jqlite. to select an element you can use querySelector() that returns first matching element or querySelectorAll() that return all matching element

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('yourelement')).prop('offsetLeft');
```

or if your "this" is valid dom element

```
angular.element(this).prop('offsetLeft');
```

**Example for div**

you can reference the DOM object with $event in html and pass it to the function on controller

```
<div ng-click="myfunction($event)"></div>
```

in controller

```
$scope.myfunction = function($event){
 console.log(angular.element($event.target).prop('offsetLeft'));

}
```

**Demo**

```js
app = angular.module('test',[]);
app.controller('testctrl',function($scope){

  
  $scope.myfunction = function($event){
    console.log($event);
 off =angular.element($event.target).prop('offsetLeft');
  angular.element($event.target).text(off)

}
  
});
```

```css
.divvy{position:absolute; left:60px;
width:100px; background:red;
}
```

```html
   

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div  ng-controller="testctrl" ng-app="test">
   <div class="divvy" ng-click="myfunction($event)" >Click to see position</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I use $scope to get the position?

Comment: $scope is not valid Dom element you can use class ot tag name in querySelector('')

Comment: are you using it in any click/hover event?

Comment: Yes, I am using ng-click. Tried with your example, but I get undefined value. It would be great if you could give complete example on how to get position of an element being clicked. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the example, but I still get undefined value

Comment: @user1995781 see output